# How to disable dead code elimination for specific blocks (or files) in webpack?

Tags: webpack

I have a code like this:

```js
const warnInDevelopment = message => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    console.warn(message);
  }
}
```

This code gets removed by webpack when I build my package, which makes sense. However, I want to disable it; so that, others who import this package/library can see the warnings in development and "hide" the warnings in production.

Comment: It is possible that this plugin will help you - [terser-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/terser/terser#compress-options) and look at `dead_code`

Comment: I want to disable it only in one file; not the entire project.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with similar code being removed as `process.env.NODE_ENV` was replaced with tokens from dotenv and then replaced in the deploy pipeline with the actual value.

Webpack5 is using terser by default for mangling and compressing. Terser have [annotations](https://github.com/terser/terser#annotations) that you can use the add hints to the process to treat function calls differently.

Break `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')` into a function that returns true/false and then add the `/*#__NOINLINE__*/` hint when you are calling the function and the code will not be eliminated, can can try it at [try.terser.org](https://try.terser.org/).

```js
const warnInDevelopment = message => {
  const isDevelopment = env => (env === 'development')
  if (/*#__NOINLINE__*/isDevelopment(process.env.NODE_ENV)) {
    console.warn(message);
  }
}

warnInDevelopment("foo");
```